# Why do mail clients try to access my UBUNTU 20.04 Postfix (v3.4.13) outgoing mail server

Tags: postfix, mail, smtp

I run a private mail server, however it is found by non associated mail clients that try to access the outgoing server smtp ports.  Why and how does this happen?  Is it hackers that look for machines that are listening on those ports and attempt to connect?

```
Jul 10 09:28:12 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[3382116]: connect from unknown[xxx.2.163.231]
Jul 10 09:28:22 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[3382116]: SSL_accept error from unknown[xxx.2.163.231]: lost connection
Jul 10 09:28:22 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[3382116]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[xxx.2.163.231]
Jul 10 09:28:22 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[3382116]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.2.163.231] commands=0/0
```

Comment: Why ask here?   Nothing you've provided has yet put you on-topic for this site, as this is a Ubuntu Q&A site and no OS/release is mentioned.

Comment: my mistake... can you suggest where this post would be appropriate as it relates to postfix smtp usage?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The on-topic link provides details & links for non Ubuntu Stack Exchange sites*

Comment: Hmmm..  Still think this question is relevant.

UBUNTU 20.02
POSTFIX mail_version = 3.4.13

Comment: Ughhh, my typo.  20.04.

Comment: This is just random noise, nothing to worry about when you keep your system updated and have strong passwords.

Comment: @pLumo - thank you for your comment.  I have been either using three different postmap db files to include some of these hits when persistent.  

client_checks.db
helo_access.db
sender_access.db

Comment: These are referred to in the /etc/postfix/main.cf  
  
`mua_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_checks,reject
mua_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access,reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions,mua_client_restrictions,mua_helo_restrictions,mua_recipient_restrictions`